# Adding classes to 'body' with JavaScript

Tags: javascript, jquery, regex, squarespace

I'm trying to add classes to the `body` of certain pages. All of the classes get added except for the 2nd, 3rd, and 4th if statements, as labeled below. I'm thinking perhaps it's because of the ordering of the if statements? I'm not sure. Can someone help me out?

```
  if (window.location.href.match(/\/shop\/\?category/)) {
      jQuery('body').addClass('shop-category');
  } else if (window.location.href.match(/\/shop\/\?category=Chef/)) { //doesn't get added
      jQuery('body').addClass('shop-category-chef');
  } else if (window.location.href.match(/\/shop\/\?category=Tactical/)) { //doesn't get added
      jQuery('body').addClass('shop-category-tactical');
  } else if (window.location.href.match(/\/shop\/\?category=Tools/)) { //doesn't get added
      jQuery('body').addClass('shop-category-tools');
  } else if (window.location.href.match(new RegExp('/shop/.+')) ) {
      jQuery('body').addClass('shop-item');
  } else if (window.location.href.match('/shop/')) {
      jQuery('body').addClass('shop');
  }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The order is the problem. `?category` matches before `?category=Chef`. Just change the order.

```
if (window.location.href.match(/\/shop\/\?category=Chef/)) {
  jQuery('body').addClass('shop-category-chef');
} else if (window.location.href.match(/\/shop\/\?category=Tactical/)) {
  jQuery('body').addClass('shop-category-tactical');
} else if (window.location.href.match(/\/shop\/\?category=Tools/)) {
  jQuery('body').addClass('shop-category-tools');
} else if (window.location.href.match(/\/shop\/\?category/)) {
  jQuery('body').addClass('shop-category');
} else if (window.location.href.match(new RegExp('/shop/.+'))) {
  jQuery('body').addClass('shop-item');
} else if (window.location.href.match('/shop/')) {
  jQuery('body').addClass('shop');
}
```